# Phantom Google font loaded?

Tags: css, google-fonts

When visiting https://assault.online/home/

There is a stylesheet loaded insecurely:

http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Old+Standard+TT:400,700,900,bold,bolder

However, this isn't in my code ANYWHERE. There are no WordPress plugins using this font, and I certainly did not load it myself.

If anyone could point me into a general direction, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere, there was an @import which loaded the file. Sigh.